# Different measurements plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How could I make a plot like these ones using matplotlib?

[image][image]

Until now I have been defining the lines by hand but I imagine that there should be an easy way of doing this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?